# Loop through m4's dumpdef

Tags: autoconf, m4

Is it possible to loop through the list of macro names given by `dumpdef`? I want to process certain macros which have a certain prefix in their name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dumpdef` writes the list of macros with their definition into a file. In [standard m4](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/m4.html), that file is standard error, so the only way to get at it is with a redirection that's external to the m4 script. GNU m4 provides the [`debugfile`](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/m4/manual/m4-1.4.17/html_node/Debug-Output.html#index-debugfile) macro to redirect the output to a file which can be read back with `input`, but you can't rely on a specific implementation of m4 in autoconf.

Even if you manage to get hold at the output from `dumpdef`, the format of the output is not specified. You can use `index` and `substr` to break a string into lines, but that assumes that the implementation prints out one macro per line, which isn't guaranteed; furthermore, macro values can contain newlines. With GNU m4, the output is ambiguous: you can't distinguish

```
define(`foo', `hello')
define(`fooo', `world')
```

from

```
 define(`foo', `hello
 fooo:   world')
```

Assuming that the m4 implementation prints one macro per line and follows the name with a colon, you can gather potential macro names this way and use `ifdef` to check whether they are indeed macro names. But you're at the mercy of an implementation that doesn't use the same debugging print format.

The best way to solve your problem is probably outside m4.

Comment: You're right, I need fix the higher layers so as not to put the burden of looping on m4. Thanks.